# Kalman-Filter for modified observation equation?

Tags: statistical-inference, control-theory, time-series, kalman-filter

The [Kalman-Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) yields the optimal estimate of the evolution of the hidden state space variable $\mathbf{X}_{t}$ from a sequence observations $\left\{ \mathbf{Y}_{t}\right\} _{t=1\ldots T}$ where
\begin{align}
\mathbf{X}_{t+1}&=A\mathbf{X}_{t}+\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{t}\\
\mathbf{Y}_{t} &=C\mathbf{X}_{t}+\boldsymbol{\delta}_{t}
\end{align}
where $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{t}$ and $\boldsymbol{\delta}_{t}$ represent the system and measurement noise (independent, Gaussian etc.). The Kalman-Filter admits even time-dependent matrices $A\to A_{t}$, $C\to C_{t}$ etc.

*My question is the following*:
I'm interested in a system with modified observation equation like
\begin{align}
\mathbf{X}_{t+1} &=A\mathbf{X}_{t}+\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{t}\\
\mathbf{Y}_{t} &=C\left(\mathbf{X}_{t}-\mathbf{X}_{t-\tau}\right)+\boldsymbol{\delta}_{t}
\end{align}
or slightly more general
\begin{align}\mathbf{X}_{t+1} &=A\mathbf{X}_{t}+\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{t}\\
\mathbf{Y}_{t} &=C_{0}\mathbf{X}_{t}+C_{1}\mathbf{X}_{t-\tau}+\boldsymbol{\delta}_{t}
\end{align}
for a fixed value of $\tau\in\mathbb{N}$. System dynamics and observation are still linear, noise still Gaussian, only the observation “mixes” different times. Can the Kalman-Filter applied to this situation as well? How does the Kalman gain matrix looks like in this situation? Does anyone know about relevant literature? Any help is appreciated.

*What I tried so far:*
I tried to simply introduce the new state space vector
$$\mathbf{Z}_{t}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{X}_{t}\\
\mathbf{X}_{t-\tau}
\end{array}\right]$$
such that one could write
$$\mathbf{Z}_{t+1} =\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A & 0\\
0 & A
\end{array}\right]\mathbf{Z}_{t}+\left[\begin{array}{c}
\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{t}\\
\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{t-\tau}
\end{array}\right]$$
with the usual observation equation
$$\mathbf{Y}_{t}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
C, & -C\end{array}\right]\mathbf{Z}_{t}+\boldsymbol{\delta}_{t}.$$
The problem, however, seems to be that in this case the noise in the equation for $\mathbf{Z}_{t}$ is no-more white noise (non-Markovian noise with non-trivial temporal correlation). So that doesn't seem to be a viable way ...

Comment: The transformed system is a time-delay system. Your idea to extend the state-vector is correct but you need to consider all the state information from $t-\tau$ to $t$ by considering the state vector $Z_t=(X_t,X_{t-1},\ldots,X_{t-\tau})$ and build a matrix $M$ that describes the dynamics of $Z_t$ using the fact that $X_{t+1}=MX_t$ plus some noise terms. If $\tau=1$, for simplicity, we have that $M=\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\I & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Then, you can design the Kalman filter using this extended system. A possible drawback is the size of the system and the resulting filter complexity.

Comment: There are other ways that do not require state augmentation. I can provide more details about that if needed. Regarding noise, it is not a problem as it is assumed that it is stationary.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply! I'm still thinking about it ...
In the meantime: Could you please provide some more information about techniques without state augmentation, because in my problem $\tau$ is typically very large.

Comment: Then, you will have to look at Kalman filters for discrete-time time-delay systems. It is a well-studied problem. You can easily find related papers and books on Google Scholar.